# DryIoC won't inject properties into ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, interceptor, dryioc, property-injection

I'm using https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/src/589e7c0b356a/NetCore/src/DryIoc.AspNetCore.Sample as baseline. Tried to implement an attribute-based property injection selector with the following:

```
private static PropertyOrFieldServiceInfo GetImportedPropertiesAndFields(MemberInfo m, Request req)
    {
        var import = (DependencyAttribute)m.GetAttributes(typeof(DependencyAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();

        return import == null ? null : PropertyOrFieldServiceInfo.Of(m)
            .WithDetails(ServiceDetails.Of(import.ContractType, import.ContractName), req);
    }
```

where `DependencyAttribute` marks the properties to be injected. **Without embedding this solution into a ASP.NET MVC Core application, it works fine.** When I try to make it inject properties in controllers with `[Dependency]` attribute within an ASP.NET Core application using `.WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(...)`, it won't work, it injects (and intercepts) only those classes, what were registered **after** taking over the services in `ConfigureServices` (and in `.AddDryIoc<TCompositionRoot>` afterwards).

Code parts what I use:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        return services.AddDryIoc<CompositionRoot>();
    }
```

DI class:

```
public static class DI
{
    public static readonly PropertiesAndFieldsSelector SelectPropertiesAndFieldsWithDependencyAttribute = PropertiesAndFields.All(withInfo: GetImportedPropertiesAndFields);

    public static IServiceProvider AddDryIoc<TCompositionRoot>(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var logger = InfrastructureFactory.CreateDefaultNLogger().CreateLogger<Startup>();

        var container = new Container()
            .WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(services, throwIfUnresolved: type => type.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
            .With(rules => rules.With(SelectPropertiesAndFieldsWithDependencyAttribute).WithoutThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient());

        container.RegisterMany<TCompositionRoot>();
        container.Resolve<TCompositionRoot>();

        logger.LogInformation("Verifying DryIoC resolutions...");

        var resolutionErrors = container.VerifyResolutions();

        if (resolutionErrors != null && resolutionErrors.Any())
        {
            foreach (var errors in container.VerifyResolutions())
            {
                logger.LogError($"DryIoC resolution error for type {errors.Key.ServiceType} : {errors.Value.Message} ({errors.Value.StackTrace})");
            }

            logger.LogWarning("DryIoC resolutions are WRONG.");
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogInformation("DryIoC resolutions are OK.");
        }

        return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    }

    #region DryIoc Property Dependency Resolver helper
    private static PropertyOrFieldServiceInfo GetImportedPropertiesAndFields(MemberInfo m, Request req)
    {
        var import = (DependencyAttribute)m.GetAttributes(typeof(DependencyAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();

        return import == null ? null : PropertyOrFieldServiceInfo.Of(m)
            .WithDetails(ServiceDetails.Of(import.ContractType, import.ContractName), req);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Additional information:

1. Constructor injection is working in controllers.
2. Searched [DryIOC Container configuration for property injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900996/dryioc-container-configuration-for-property-injection) thoroughly, but it is about a WebApi application, not the case I try.
3. I tried to switch the order of `.WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(...)` and `.With(rules => ...)` with no luck.
4. Interception not working for controllers also. I'm using @dadhi's recommendation for interception: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/Interception . BTW, how do you register an interceptor for a Controller with Castle and DryIoC?
5. I won't copy `CompositionRoot` class here; it is boring, long and not relevant.

Any ideas to get controller property injection and controller method interception work?

Comment: DryIoC.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 1.2.2

Castle.Core 4.0.0

Comment: Did you specify `AddControllersAsServices()` on configured service collection?

Comment: @dadhi `AddControllersAsServices()` did the trick, property injection as well as interception is now working. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have added property injection example into sample Startup.cs (https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/src/97313c27a0bcf9a5236271d94681dac47bf9380c/NetCore/src/DryIoc.AspNetCore.Sample/Startup.cs?at=dev&fileviewer=file-view-default). You can check on LoggingController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify `AddControllersAsServices()` on configured service collection. [This](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/04/asp-net-mvc-6-discovers-controllers/) explains why.

The [Sample](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/src/97313c27a0bcf9a5236271d94681dac47bf9380c/NetCore/src/DryIoc.AspNetCore.Sample/Startup.cs?at=dev&fileviewer=file-view-default) is already including this, as well as property injection example.

Comment: We are required to move to new .NET framework (7) and it seems that this approach (attribute-based property injection) doesn't work anymore, at least not in newer .NET (in .NET 5 it works fine). We have the fixed Startup/ConfigureServices code with AddControllersAsServices(), but seemingly DryIoc (or the default Controller creation mechanism) won't inject these properties, only if explicitly resolved (so with explicit resolution it works perfectly, but when aspnet resolves a controller the properties are null). @dadhi could you pls help?

Comment: Actually the approach (paradigm) services.AddDryIoc<CompositionRoot>() doesn't seem to work anymore in .NET v>5 (I mean it works, but somehow attribute-based property injections are not). We were required to move to a new approach: register with the builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory() approach which seems to work - as how it is suggested by DryIoC sample https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/tree/edec0182ca1611f29a00f7e4145da8d63315e439/samples/DryIoc.AspNetCore.Sample

Comment: @Peter I would suggest for you to go to the Discussions tab in DryIoc repo and provide the sample/ describe what is not working for you. Then I can help.